# issues using X-Forwarded-For Log Filter for Windows Servers

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7, windows-server-2008, isapi

I've encountered some problems trying to use X-Forwarded-For Log Filter for Windows Servers.
I've downloaded binaries (x86 version) and followed to installation manual from http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/08/19/x_forwarded_for_log_filter_for_windows_servers.aspx,
but when I try to open a web-page on my site I get an error:

---

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>    Calling GetProcAddress on ISAPI filter "C:\ISAPI Filters\F5XFFHttpModule\F5XFFHttpModule.dll" failed
>   Module               IIS Web Core 
>   Notification        Unknown 
>   Handler               StaticFile
>  
>   Error Code          0x8007007f

**System Info:**

OS - Windows Server 2008 Datacenter, 32-bit
IIS - 7.0
.NET   Framework Version - 4.0
ISAPI Extensions & ISAPI Filters installed   ok.

Filter is added to ISAPI and CGI Restrictions and to ISAPI filters for web-application too.
IIS user (UISR) has read and execute access permissions for F5XFFHttpModule.dll.
Web-application application pool works on .NET Framework 4 in Integrated mode, Process Model Identity - NetworkService(changing Process Model to ApplicationPool doesn't help).
Debug version doesn't create any log file:(

What I see in windows event log:

> The HTTP Filter DLL C:\ISAPI Filters\F5XFFHttpModule\F5XFFHttpModule.dll failed to load.  The data ithe error.
>   Could not load all ISAPI filters for site '%sitename%'.  Therefore site startup aborted.

However the filter works fine in Windows7 x64 + IIS7.5. An error described here is fixed by setting "Enable 32-bit Application" to true in web-application application pool settings.
Be so kind to help me to puzzle out this trouble please.

Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out.

I use downloaded `HTTP` module as `ISAPI` filter, i.e without installing it in IIS - it's my error Now I run install.ps1 script from HTTP module distrib(http://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/Joe/archive/2009/12/23/x-forwarded-for-http-module-for-iis7-source-included.aspx), and all work fine!

thanks to Joe Pruitt for help!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let us know the solution! When you can, please mark this as the accepted answer by clicking the tick on the left hand side - This will let others know an answer has been found without looking at the page in detail.